# How to determine if should I adopt a time series approach given a dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, dataset

I'm learning about machine learning and data science and I Would like to know, given a dataset which contains "Date" as one of it's many features. How to determine if I'm facing a time series problem where I can use ARIMA, SARIMA or maybe a machine learning model like XGBoost or otherwise treat this dataset as a "normal" one? Maybe "Date" is not too related with the target as other features or maybe the target has classes. So how to identify a time series problem?

Comment: It is the task/goal that informs you whether to consider time-series approach. Not the dataset.

Comment: All tutorials I read uses datasets with one input feature only and date/time as index but in kaggle i'm studing a dataset called "rain in australia" and the task is tell if is gonna rain tomorrow. So, I tought I was facing a time series problem because basides it has date feature. But the thing is this dataset has many other features like "Location", "Humidity", "RainToday" and I don't know anymore if I should consider treat it like a time series problem or a "normal" one.

Comment: If the task is forecasting into a time in the future, and there is historical data available then definitely this is a time-series problem. If you have multiple locations that are reasonably close/related, then it might also make sense to consider it as spatio-temporal (having location and time).